# A part of my screen can't change

Tags: kubuntu, display, opengl

My kubuntu can't refresh the lower part of my screen :

[image]

When I restart openGL, it's refreshing the display once.
But then the lower part is still stucked.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: I tried to reboot and I also switched to another driver via the driver manager, but it does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to another resolution and then revert to the original resolution.

It did the trick.

But I still don't understand why this bug happened in the first place.